# Rabin's cryptography - when the message $M$ isn't coprime to $n = pq$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, cryptography

Say the message $M$ is a product of one of the primes $p$ or $q$, won't the $gcd$ of $M$ and $n$ (the public encryption key) give me $p$ or $q$?

say $p = 11$ $q=19$ $n=11*19=209$ and $M=33$.

$gcd(33, 209) = 11$. and I know that if the $gcd$ isn't $1$ then it's one of the primes..

Because $gcd's$ running time is very fast, I can just try and do this with every message I send.. What am I missing?

Comment: You need a **huge** lot of messages to find one that isn't coprime to the modulus, unless you already know something about the modulus.

Comment: So it's just a matter of low probability.. something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Closer to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$, the probability that you hit a message not coprime to $n$ is $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} - \frac{1}{pq}$. But if $p$ and $q$ are primes with something like $500$ bits each ...

Comment: So, if $n\approx 2^{1000}$, $gcd(n, M)'s$ running time is $\mathcal{O}(log(n)^3)$ which is $\mathcal{O}(1000^3)$. We need to do this around $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$ times that's $\approx 2^{499}$. Thats $\mathcal{O}(10^62^{499})$ operations.
Yes thats pretty big..

Comment: FYI, there is a [Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Crypto.SE has [explored this problem](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25649/706) before.